# How to detect if my app is running on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Is there a way to detect if a rails app is running on Heroku?

I want to make a method like:

```
def on_heroku?
...
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may set your own [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) to use for detection via `ENV['var']`.

`$ heroku config:add I_AM_HEROKU=yes`

```
def on_heroku?
  ENV['I_AM_HEROKU']
end
```

Answer (score 5):

```
def heroku?
  ENV.any? {|x,_| x=~ /^HEROKU/ }
end
```

Comment: This has an advantage over the accepted answer in that it will succeed in detecting a Heroku deployment (provided that you're using something like Heroku postgres, which adds a HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COLOR_URL key to your env hash) without requiring you to remember to set an environment variable.