# How to detect if my ruby app is running on heroku without config:add?

Tags: ruby, heroku, bundler

In Gemfile, I want to write pseudocode:

```
ruby: '1.9.3' if ENV['HEROKU']
```

Because I want to run my app on another platform, version like jruby, ruby2.0.0 if !heroku. I think this is heroku specific var, HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_VIOLET_URL

```
ruby: '1.9.3' if ENV['HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_VIOLET_URL']
```

What is more better way to do?

Related:
[How to detect if my app is running on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819322/how-to-detect-if-my-app-is-running-on-heroku)

Oops, HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_{VIOLET,SLIVER,RED,...}_URL, this is distributed.

Comment: so whats the problem with the linked question?

Comment: you want dev/staging/prod parity. Using different versions of ruby is not parity. Why are you doing that?

Comment: @phoet I want this app to rubygems, so I want to reduce "heroku config:add HEROKU=1" manually. I'll forget. I prefer this: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/Gemfile#L46 "!ENV['TRAVIS']"

Comment: @hgmnz yes, using fifferent version, https://github.com/sanemat/kagari/blob/master/.travis.yml but on heroku specific, I want to one ruby version https://github.com/sanemat/kagari/blob/master/Gemfile#L2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that `if ENV.keys.any? {|var_name| var_name.match(/heroku/i) }` would be a relatively sane approach.

Comment: Good! Thanks! but I feel this is temporary solution ;(

Comment: In 2015 there is no longer any key matching /heroku/i, but there is one matching /dyno/i (if the better solution linked above is really not applicable).

Answer (score -2):

If you don't want to add another environment variable, you could change Rails environment from 'production' to 'heroku' (but it should be done by changing environment variable `RAILS_ENV` anyway).

Therefore, locally your Rails environment will be development/test/production, but on Heroku it will be 'heroku' and you'll be able to check:

```
Rails.env.heroku?
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This does not work in the bundler stage, as Rails is not defined there.